# Footer of the page for the mobile version

Tags: css, dom, mobile, version, footer

Good day,

How can I set the footer of the page for the mobile version?

I tested on DOM different position but it does not work. When I tested, for mobile version, my footer disappears from the mobile page, and other sites I did not found anything for mobile versions

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

your question isn't entirely clear, but you can use media queries to adjust the styling of your footer depending on the viewport size.

an example:

```css
    @media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
      footer {
        background-color: lightgreen;
        width: 100%;
        etc...
      }
    }
```